# Whats the best way to put a customized scrollable list in android studios?

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, uicollectionview

I'm trying to make a android app with a scrollable list like this one...

[image]

When I made this app in iOS, I used a `UICollectionView`. What`s the best way to make this in android studios?

I tried using a list view, but I can't seem to customize it to my needs?

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ListView was a great way to start and it is customizable to your needs.
However I would recommend to use RecyclerView which works almost on the same principle as ListView but it is a newer concept in Android. It handles the usage of the ViewHolder pattern for you which makes everything super easy.(With ListView, you would've had to implement your own ViewHolder pattern)

All you need to do is to have the RecyclerView in your activity/fragment as the view to hold your data. Then, the key component is to implement the RecyclerView's Adapter which will handle the inflation and setup of each list item.

[Here](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html) is a really great and short tutorial to get you started with RecyclerView.

If you're done with that [here is a bit more advanced video material on RecyclerView](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-C5I1DAviJ8) from Dave Smith explaining a lot of ways on how to understand and use RecyclerView in your apps.

Answer (score 1):

A ListView fed by an ArrayAdapter of custom objects can do the job.

You might have a class that contains the text and the image of a single item.

Then you can create an ArrayList with items of that class, where you put in all the data.

This ArrayList can be used as dataset for a custom ArrayAdapter, which overrides the getView()-method.

The getView()-method must inflate the xml-layout for each item and attach the data from the ArrayList to the inflated view.

You might want to implement the Viewholder-pattern to achieve a good performance and avoid unnecessary inflations and getViewByID()-calls.

You can also use the new CardView, which can make it a lot easier, since it is made for the new material design in android 5, which looks similar to your item list.